# why does `make` using _CoqProject in coqide differ from `coqc` on the commandline?

Tags: coq, coqide

I have two short files: cc_test is given by 
`Lemma cc: 4 = 4. Proof. auto. Qed.`
and libtest is given by 
`Require Import cc_test.  Check cc.`

When I execute 
`coqc -R . ClosureLib -top ClosureLib cc_test` 
in directory "/home/barry/svn/Coq/Closure_Calculus" 
and 
`coqc -R "/home/barry/svn/Coq/Closure_Calculus" ClosureLib libtest`
in its directory, I get the expected output 
`cc: 4 = 4`

However, when the arguments to coqc above (from -R to the end) are placed in _CoqProject files, and I call `Make makefile` and then `Make` from the coqide menu, cc_test is okay but libtest yields output 
`File "./libtest.v", line 1, characters 15-22:
Error: Unable to locate library cc_test.`

How should I modify the project files to make this work?

Comment: the coq reference manual (Chapter 15) does not mention any differences between these approaches. Also, the argument "-top ClosureLib" 
seems to be necessary in the commandline approach, but does not appear to matter using `make` as, in other experiments, I frequently get error messages saying that it found Top.foo but not ClosureLib.foo.

Comment: Have you tried with Coq 8.7? CoqIDE Make feature used to not care about the `_CoqProject` file. This was fixed in https://github.com/coq/coq/pull/1025.

Answer (score 2):

First, I do not think `-top ClosureLib` is useful here. The [documentation](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/commands.html#coqoptions) describes `-top` as

> Not valid for coqc as the toplevel module name is inferred from the
>   name of the output file

As for your main question, I must admit my solution is to install the dependencies using

```
coq_makefile -f _CoqProject -o Makefile
make
make install
```

`make install` puts the libraries in `user-contrib`, a place where they will be loaded automatically. You can then use `Require` directly.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to @Zimm48, I understood how to use `$COQPATH` to accomplish the same task without having to install the dependencies first. But the name of the folder will be used as the logical prefix, so you must use the same identifier in the `-R` or `-Q` argument and for the name of the directory.

I would suggest to use the following architecture:

- in directory `/home/barry/svn/Coq/ClosureLib` (note that I renamed the directory, so that its name is identical to the identifier passed to `-R`), `_CoqProject` contains

  ```
  -R . ClosureLib
  cc_test.v
  ```

  You compile cc_test.v as follows:

  ```
  coq_makefile -f _CoqProject -o Makefile
  make
  ```
- in the directory containing `libtest.v`, `_CoqProject` contains

  ```
  -R . MyLib
  libtest.v
  ```

  You can compile `libtest.v` as follows:

  ```
  coq_makefile -f _CoqProject -o Makefile
  COQPATH=/home/barry/svn/Coq make
  ```

Comment: If I read the question correctly, there is no "dependency" here in the sense that both files are supposed to be part of the same logical and physical directory.

Comment: It is not clear in the question. The fact that the user specifies an absolute path made me assume that there were two different folders, but I may have misinterpreted the question.