# How to import the file in other project/directory by configuring the Makefile or _Coqproject in current project

Tags: coq

I would like to import the file of one of my projects when coding the current project.

i.e. Import the file **../ProjectA/fileA.v** in **./fileB.v**.

How can I do this via configuring the Makefile or _Coqproject.

Comment: You can execute `make install` in `ProjectA` so that it is visible from `ProjectB`, or you can use the `COQPATH` environment variable to add `ProjectA` path to the locations used by Coq to locate libraries. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47087271/why-does-make-using-coqproject-in-coqide-differ-from-coqc-on-the-commandlin/47160117#47160117) or [this](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/4990).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add the following line at the beginning of the `_CoqProject`:

```
-R ../ProjectA SomeName
```

And then you should be able to write

```
From SomeName Require Import fileA.
```